# addEventListener on image link not working

Tags: javascript

I am using the code below to capture what links are clicked and passing them for a short time to a form that needs to redirect folks back to where they wanted to go.  It works perfectly.

```js
    //Get all anchor tags on the page 
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 
     
    //Loop through all the links and attach an event listener to each 
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { 
        links[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
    
        var date = new Date();
        var expiry='; expires='+date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * 1000));
        document.cookie='click_link='+event.target.href+expiry+'; path=/';
        }); 
    }
```

```html
<a class="elementor-icon elementor-animation-pulse-shrink" href="https://example.org/path/page/">
  <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-map-marked-alt"></i> Some text
</a>
```

I'm not overly skilled in JS so I also tried to test if event.target.href is "undefined" but could not.  Technically either solution works.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It looks like your code sets the same single cookie over and over again.

Comment: Change all your `var` declarations to `let`.

Comment: As well as the above issues, I think you have a problem with `event.target`, if the event is bubbling from the image to the anchor, you will need `currentTarget` ([MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)) as the `target` doesn't have an `href`

Comment: Correct, it currently resets the cookie each time a new link is set and allows that info to be picked up elsewhere.

Will do on the var = let.

@DBS I will test this, thank you.